# How to list versioned files in git?

Tags: git, bazaar

I would like to list the versioned files in the root directory of a git repository. To do the same thing in bazaar, you run:

```
bzr ls --versioned --non-recursive
```

How do I do this in git?

Comment: I'd call these *tracked* files in git, which is why this didn't come up in my google results. I guess that's not worth posting a duplicate, so here's the keyword.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It would be more helpful if you described exactly what listing you want to show. Guessing from the bzr document, I imagine that you want something like this.

```
git ls-tree --name-only HEAD
```

This lists the names of files in the current directory which are currently in the `HEAD` revision, which should be close to what you are asking for.

Comment: And `git ls-tree --name-only HEAD ./` for only things under the current directory.

Comment: How is that different to `git ls-files`?

Answer (score 8):

I do not know what "bzr ls --versioned --non-recursive" does, but I suspect that it is either

- "[git ls-tree](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-tree.html) --name-only HEAD" (like [Charles Bailey wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441317/what-is-the-git-equivalent-of-bzr-ls-versioned-non-recursive/1441361#1441361)), which lists files at given revision, and by default is non-recursive

or

- "[git ls-files](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html)" (perhaps additionally with --cached and --exclude-standard options), which lists specified kinds of files (by default it is files that are in index), and is recursive (and currently there is no way to turn off being recursive, as far as I know).